# Doob-Dynkin Lemma, Kallenberg proof issue

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-explanation, conditional-expectation

In Foundations of Modern Probability, Kallenberg, (2nd edition) page 7, lemma 1.13 the following proof is given:

[image: Kallenberg - Foundations of Modern Probability (2nd edition) page 7-8]

I can understand how the proof goes through if we assume that the measure space $(S,\pmb{S})$ is a **standard Borel space** (that is, a polish space with the Borel sigma algebra corresponding to the polish topology) , since then we may apply Kuratowski's theorem which says that $(S,\pmb{S})$ is Borel isomorphic to $(F = \{x_1,...,x_k\}, 2^F)$ or $(\mathbb{N},2^{\mathbb{N}})$ in which case we can prove the theorem directly for these cases, and if it is uncountable it is borel isomorphic to $([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]))$ and we may proceed as Kallenberg does, but if $(S,\pmb{S})$ is merely Borel isomorphic to a Borel subset of $[0,1]$ then I do not see that we can ensure it is standard Borel, and so Kuratowksi's theorem may not apply, so how can we further reduce to the case when $S = [0,1]$ as Kallenberg suggests?

Comment: Borel sets are isomorphic to $[0,1]$, or a countable set. That is a deep theorem in measure theory. As a consequence, all uncountable Borel sets are measurable  isomorphic .

Comment: I think this only applies to standard borel spaces ? Are you referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Borel_space#Kuratowski's_theorem ? I mentioned this in my post, but Kallenberg only assumes $(S,\pmb{S})$ is borel isomorphic to a borel subset of $[0,1]$, but does this necessarily imply $(S,\pmb{S})$ is standard borel? That is does this imply that $S$ is a polish space? If it were borel isomorphic to something like a $G_{\sigma}$ subset of $[0,1]$ then I would agree, but any borel set?

Comment: So a 'borel set' in his book is actually supposed to be interpreted as a 'standard borel space' ? He does define a borel set before this lemma as any measure space that is borel isomorphic to a borel subset of the real line (or $[0,1]$, which would be an equivalent characterization), but does not say that these borel subsets of the real line/unit interval need to be polish, in which case there is a difference between these two terminologies. I will check the book of Parthasarathy to see if there is the same result presented in a different way.

Comment: Take a look at this [note](http://math.iisc.ac.in/~manju/MartBM/RaoSrivastava_borelisomorphism.pdf) which summarizes what I was trying to get across.

Comment: Many thanks, I can see that proposition 2 of that note is essentially what I need.

Comment: More importantly, look at the last result. In that link I sent you, a Borel set (or space) is a Borel subset of a Polish space. The main result is that all Borel subsets measurably isomorphic to a finite set, a countable set or $[0,1]$ according to their cardinality. That is is mostly all is needed to build Probability theory at the foundational level.